# All hats are disabled even if I meet the unlock requirements for some of them

Tags: support, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

When looking at my hats on the Winter Bash site, all of the hats are grey with the following message `You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet.` even if I think I should already have unlocked some of them.

For example I have already a silver badge on `Stack Overflow` but the `IDENTIFICATION DIVISION` hat is not active?!

Am I missing something around here? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your silver badge is a Yearling badge you got back in May. Sadly, the badge required for the IDENTIFICATION DIVISION hat has to be acquired during the Winter Bash period.

In other words: your Yearly badge does not count because you acquired it before Winter Bash started.

(Also worth noticing that usually hats are awarded with a little delay, so after meeting some hat requirements give the system at least 20min to process the new hats before starting worrying )

Comment: Ah ok, so you have to meet the unlock requirements during the `winter bash`! Thanks!

Comment: @DominicJonas yes, at least for most of the hats it works that way. There may be some exception to this rule in some special cases (for example, I seems to remember some years ago there was an hat that required you to have posted something on a specific day **before** the event started)